# $X$ and $Y$ correlation coefficient of $2/3$ , find $\mathrm{Var}(3X − 5Y+ 7)$

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to solve this simple problem but I realize that I am missing something. Here is the problem:

> $X$ and $Y$ have correlation coefficient of $2/3$ and $\mathrm{Var}(X)=1$ and $\mathrm{Var}(Y)=9$. Fine $\mathrm{Var}(3x - 5Y + 7)$.  Also find $E(X^2Y)$

[image]

Now I realize that since we have the correlation coefficient as being $2/3$, I have solved for the $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)=2$. Also, I know that if $X$ and $Y$ were independent, then...

$$\mathrm{Var}(3x - 5Y + 7)\\
\mathrm{Var}(3x) + \mathrm{Var}(-5Y) + \mathrm{Var}(7)$$

Which is $234$. However, that cannot be correct since there is a correlation between $X$ and $Y$ right? Also for the  $E(X^2Y)$, I am not sure. I am not sure why they gave us the joint pdf as I feel it is of no use.

Help would greatly appreciated!!

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the variance of $3X-5Y+7$, the $7$ part doesn't matter.

And in general 
$$\text{Var}(aX+bY)=a^2\text{Var}(X)+b^2\text{Var}(Y)+2ab\text{Cov}(X,Y).$$

Here $a=3$ and $b=-5$.  Since you know the correlation coefficient of $X$ and $Y$, you can compute the covariance by multiplying by the square root of $\text{Var}(X)\text{Var}(Y)$.  Thus we have all the necessary ingredients.

The finding of $E(X^2Y)$ may refer to the table. We need to add up $x^2yf(x,y)$ over all pairs $(x,y)$ in the table, where $f(x,y)$ is the probability that $X=x$ and $Y=y$.

So let's go through the table, first row left to right, then second row, then third. Our first term in the sum is $(1^2)(2)(0.05)$. The second term is $(1^2)(4)(0.14)$. The third is $(1^2)(6)(0.1)$. The fourth is $(2^2)(2)(0.25)$. And so on.

We end up with $9$ terms. Add them up.

Comment: Ah yes, I see where my mistake was! Thank you very much indeed :)

Comment: You are welcome. Soon this sort of calculation will be routine.